# Benefits of Firestore timestamp over js date

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Why does firestore use [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) of its own instead of the plain js date object?
I searched the docs and couldn't find any benefits other than nanoseconds precision.
But I don't think that its of any much use given that the native js date object only supports upto ms precision(and intuitively firestore timestamp in js sdk must be built over the plain js date object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Firestore has client libraries for many different languages.  They are not all JavaScript, so a JavaScript Date object would not be sufficient to cover all those languages.  And, as you know, the timestamp has nanosecond precision, so a Date object with millisecond precision would not itself be sufficient without losing data.

Firestore's timestamp must be portable, so each language has is provided its own Timestamp class describing its two components for seconds and nanoseconds.  Most programming languages don't have a natural nanosecond precision representation of a point in time, nor do they have an integer type sized correctly to combine them in a single value. So, Timestamp class is provided as an abstraction that's useful for comparing two timestamp fields for equality and order, since it's not as simple as comparing two integer values to each other.

You're not obliged to use it if you don't want to.  It's there simply because it's required for full compatibility, to avoid losing precision.  If you want to question the Firestore engineers directly about their decision to use nanosecond precision, you can post to the [google-cloud-firestore-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss) forum to start a discussion.

Comment: Makes sense for sure!

Answer (score 0):

As peronal experience I found very usefull to use seconds over date object or date as string , I was able to make easy mongodb query (we used mongodb for search and firestore for managment) for example when searching within interval.